# Netbeans eats my comments when I inline

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

When I do <kbd>Refactor</kbd> > <kbd>Inline...</kbd>, Netbeans eats my Java comments. I find this quite annoying. I'd like to decide for myself when my comments should be deleted, thank you very much.

Example:

```
    double a = 1;
    //Important comment! DO NOT DELETE!
    double inlineMe = 2 * a;
    double b = 4 * inlineMe;
```

Example diff:

[image]

Is it possible to prevent this behaviour, and if so, how?

I browsed through Tools > Options and couldn't find anything that would do this.

Comment: I think your behavior is pertaining netbeans and not just java removing java tag.

Comment: I tried it in java using intellij an could not reproduce it...

Comment: @wrongAnswer: No, obviously, that's not what I meant. What I'm saying is, I don't have evidence to say that this happens in other languages in Netbeans; only in Java in Netbeans. I'm putting the Java tag back in until someone shows that this is a more generalized problem in Netbeans.

Comment: Do you have any other languages that you can use in Netbeans? In other words, can that someone be you?

Comment: @yshavit: It can, but it wouldn't really get me closer to answering my own question, so it doesn't seem like an important path of investigation. Look, I thought I tagged my question fairly and accurately given the information available, but I certainly don't want to get into a bickering match about tags, so if someone feels strongly about the Java tag, be my guest.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked on NetBeans 8.0.1 on the C++ module, highlighted "inlineMe", right clicked it, selected Refactor, and there's no "Inline" option, so it looks like this particular feature is not available to all modules (i.e. keep the Java tag).

This looks like a bug to me, and it would not be the first in NetBeans' refactoring either.

I could understand if the comment was on the side of the line, but not if it's on top of it.

I searched the [Bugzilla](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/) with "inline comment", but could not find anything about this issue. I suggest you open a report about this.